# htmlentities, htmlspecialchars and ajax issue

Tags: php, ajax

Trying to use htmlentities/htmlspecialchars with ajax call and it does not convert to html tag when remote output is rendered back onto the originating script.

I've searched all over for a solution but could not find one, so here I am.

All works well without applying htmlentities, but I got this scanned for XSS and came up as potential issue.

Here is the relevant portion of the code in the remote php file:

```
<select class = "hook1" id = "<?php echo $version ; ?>" name="vdiesel" >
<option>Version essence</option>
<?php
while ($r= $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { 
$out="<option   value='".$r['version_id'].'|'.$r['vid_diesel']."'>".$r['version']."</option>";
//echo $out;
echo htmlentities($out, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
}
echo "</select>";
```

And the relevant?? portion of the ajax call:

```
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType:"html",       
    url: url, 
    beforeSend: function () {
  $("#"+ selbot).html("<option>Loading ...</option>");
    },
    data: {passval:pass_id, pass2:selbot},
   success: function(data){
     $("#"+ selbot).html(data);
   }
   });
```

This is an example of the response from Firebug console:

```
<select class = "hook1" id = "version9" name="vdiesel" >
<option>Version essence</option>
&lt;option value=&#039;685|686&#039;&gt;Pop Star Essence&lt;/option&gt;
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

The above gets printed onto the html correctly, except for the line sanitized with htmlentities, which gets printed out as below, apparently correct but without recognizing the html tag:

```
<option value='685/686'>Pop Star Essence</option>
```

I am certainly missing some basic stuff, hope you will let me know.
Thanks

Comment: The whole point of `htmlentities()` is to render the value literally, instead of interpreting it as HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are encoding too much.

You should just encode the values you get from the database so that they cannot break the html (and do not pose an XSS risk...):

```
$out="<option value='".htmlentities($r['version_id'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')
       .'|'.htmlentities($r['vid_diesel'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')."'>"
       .htmlentities($r['version'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')."</option>";
```

Comment: Thanks both of you for a quick and precise answer. This solved my issue and helped me better understand the usage of htmlentities. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You're using `htmlentities()` in the wrong place. It should be used only on the part of the data that should be shown literally, not the HTML container.

```
while ($r= $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { 
    $out="<option   value='" . htmlentities($r['version_id'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') . '|' . htmlentities($r['vid_diesel'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') . "'>". htmlentities($r['version'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') . "</option>";
    echo $out;
}
```